# Nested Exponentials

Tags: real-analysis

I solved the following "nested exponentials equations on Desmos and got $x = 0.577$ and $x = 1.65$.

(1)   $\ x^{x^x} = \ 0.5^{x}$

And

(2)   $\ x^{x^x} = 2^{x}$

Then I tried to solve the problem (2)  using the following algebraic technique:

$\ \ln (x^{x^x})   = \ln (2^{x}) $

$\ (x^{x}) \ln(x)  = x \ln(2) $

$\ (x^{x}\cdot x^{-1}) (\ln(x))  = \ln(2) $

$\ \ln(x^x\cdot x^{-1}) + \ln(\ln(x))  = \ln(\ln(2)) $

$\ \ln(x^{x})-1 \ln(x)   + \ln(\ln(x))  = \ln(\ln(2)) $

$\ x \ln(x) -1 \ln(x)   + \ln(\ln(x))  = \ln(\ln(2)) $

$\ x \ln(x) -1 \ln(x)   + \ln(\ln(x))  = -0.3667 $

$\  (x - 1) \ln(x)    + \ln(\ln(x))  = -0.3667 $

I don't see how to further reduce this equation either into a Lambert form or use some substitution. Since it has one solution of $x = 1.65$, one would think there would be a quick, algebraic solution. Maybe not.  Any suggestions are appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: There’s a difference between $x^{(x^x)}$ and  $(x^x)^x$

Comment: Thanks, Eric for the hint.  Will do some more searching/thinking.

Comment: Most transcendental equations like this don't have an explicit analytic solution, even if you allow the use of Lambert W function. I'd bet that that's the case with this one.

Comment: @jjagmath: Thank you.  I was beginning to think much the same thing.  I have revised the question and inserted the answer from Desmos of 1.65.  Left side equals the right side, so up to this point, I believe I've done the math correctly.  Could you tell me how I might repost a question on MathStack after editing. Thank you. Fred

Comment: @Frederick You want to solve $x^{x^{x-1}}=2^{\pm1}$. There is a series expansion for the inverse of $x^{x^{x-1}}$, but it does not converge for $2,\frac12$. Would you like the solution for $x^{x^x}=a^x$ converging about for $0.7<|a|<1.4$? [Example](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=lim%5B1%2Bsum%5Bln%280.8%29%5En%2Fn%21+D%5Be%5Ew+%28e%5E%28-%28-1+%2B+e%5Ew%29+w%29%29%5En%2C%7Bw%2Cn-1%7D%5D%2C%7Bn%2C1%2C9%7D%5D%2Cw-%3E0.0%5D) [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=x%5Ex%5Ex%3D0.8%5Ex). The derivatives can be taken to give an exact series solution